# select group by with multiple AND conditions on the same columns

Tags: select, group-by

I've an sql table like this:

```
SID|SERVICE_SID|ATTRIBUTE_SID|VALUE
1    2           5             "VAL1"
2    2           4             "VAL8"
3    2           3             "VAL4"
4    11          5             "VAL1"
5    11          3             "VAL4"
```

I'd like to group by service_SID where ***for the same service_sid***:

AND (attribute_sid = 5 && Value="VAL1")

AND (attribute_sid = 4 && Value="VAL8")

So, in this case, only a row with service_sid = 2 should be returned.

Is this a query like this even possible? What would it look like?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: HSQL for the moment, but i'm planning to use MS Sequel server. But ideally, I'd like it to be as much dbms agnostic as possible..

Comment: What is the final goal, because if you want to group by `service_SID` why just you use `GROUP BY service_SID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `INTERSECT` which is available in both [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_set_operations) and SQL Server

```
SELECT SERVICE_SID
FROM SQLTable
WHERE attribute_sid = 5 AND Value='VAL1'
INTERSECT
SELECT SERVICE_SID
FROM SQLTable
WHERE attribute_sid = 4 AND Value='VAL8';
```

You can then join the result of this query with your table and `group by SERVICE_SID`